# overlay on HDMI

Tags: video

will it ever be possible to overlay say ubuntu over a HDMI video feed so that when a button is pressed it will show the taksbar etc over the video that is playing.

chumby's netv does something similar  ? we could make a really good multi room av system with this

Answer (score 1):

If you mean have a video feed being displayed by the computer that happens to be going out on an HDMI cable, then sure.  If you mean take an existing HDMI video feed and overlay the desktop, then no, as that would require a video card with an HDMI input, and I don't think there is such a thing.